# Is there a way to truncate element's text in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this element:

```
"<span class=interests><a href=>Acoustics</a><a href=>Actuarial Studies</a><a href=>Administrative Law</a></span>"
```

I want to truncate this by a's text e.g: Acoustics in the above example. If it is more than 50,  I want to truncate it.

How can I do that with jQuery?

Comment: Do a google search for ellipsis plugins.

Comment: Trivially: `e.text(e.text().substr(0, 50))` - but you are probably interested in more sophisticated approaches.

Comment: [Just use css?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow)

Comment: @AdamMerrifield CSS can't limit by character count (which may be a good thing, but it doesn't fulfill the requirement).

Comment: @user2864740 That's why I'm posting a comment instead of an answer. More times than not you don't want to truncate text based on a random number of characters that can be any length due to varying character widths. You probably want to truncate based on a container's layout. It's just a suggestion that there is a better way.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    <span id="mainText" >
<a>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</a></span>
    <script>
      jQuery(document).ready(function(){
      $('span a').each(function(a, v){
          if ($(this).text().length>50){
              $(this).remove();
          }
      })


})
</script>
```

Comment: He doesn't want to remove it all, just truncate it to 50 characters.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.interests a').each(function(){
    var truncated = $(this).text().substr(0, 50);
    //Updating with ellipsis if the string was truncated
    $(this).text(truncated+(truncated.length<50?'':'[...]'));
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/abrhmcc/x8pkorjn/6/)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following :

```
$('span a').each(function(){
    if($(this).text().length > 50)
        $(this).text($(this).text().substr(0,50));
});
```

Comment: this applies trim to all the text of anchor. What i want is to find the number of characters in all anchor's text and then truncate them.

Comment: <a href="">ABC</a><a href="">DEF</a> If ABCDEF.length > 3 lets says it will be seen like this: ABC...

Comment: Here to get total size : var i = 0; $('span a').each(function(){i = i + $(this).text().length;}); after that I still don't understand what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Passing a function to the text method will let you change the text dynamically

```
$('a').text(function( index, value ) {
  if (value.length > 50){
  return value.substr(0, 50);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> ABCDEF If ABCDEF.length > 3 lets says it will be seen like this: ABC... –  real1 42 mins ago

?

```
<span class='interests'>
    <a href='#'>Acoustics</a>
    <a href='#'>Actuarial Studies</a>
    <a href='#'>Administrative Law</a>
    <a href='#'>Something inside your head, Something inside your head, Something inside your head, Something inside your head</a>
</span>
```

Then:

```
var total = 0;
var truncated = "";

$('.interests a').each(function(){
    total+=$(this).text().length;
    truncated+=$(this).text();
});

if(total>50){
    truncated = truncated.substring(0, 50)+'...';
    $('.interests').html(truncated);    
}
```

You get:

```
AcousticsActuarial StudiesAdministrative LawSometh...
```

Discarding the links?

http://jsfiddle.net/abrhmcc/x8pkorjn/7/